# I made Hashtag system for my website but after using special characters like " ' " or " ; " and so on it makes #hashtag in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

[image]

I have uploaded an screen shot of the issue. I've tried to use SAFE but it doesn't work.

> post.content|safe|hashchange

Hope someone can help me here

Comment: Have you tried just `post.content|safe`?  Because :If you are chaining filters, a filter applied after safe can make the contents unsafe again. For example, the following code prints the variable as is, unescaped: {{ var|safe|escape }}

Comment: I've tried both ways, still I get the same issue